# Returning pointer to static constant string via function

Tags: c, pointers

I have a file which has a static constant string and a function which will return pointer to that string.
File looks like this:

```
typedef unsigned char   BOOLEAN;

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0


static const unsigned char MAL_Version[8] = "2.001";

/* Function to return Version string */
BOOLEAN GetVersion ( unsigned char* pu8Version )
{
    BOOLEAN success = FALSE;

    if(pu8Version != NULL)
    {
        pu8Version = &MAL_Version[0];
        success = TRUE;
        printf("\r\nTRUE");
        printf("\r\n%s", pu8Version);
    }

    return success;
}
```

and in main(), I declare an array and pass it's address to GetVersion function.
When I do this, I am getting random characters.

```
int main() {
   unsigned char buffer[10];

   GetVersion(buffer);
   printf("\r\n%s", buffer);
}
```

Output is:

TRUE

2.001

D�3�

What I am missing? The pointer in function is correctly printing the string, but when it returns, it prints garbage.

Comment: why you using `typedef unsigned char   BOOLEAN;`, instead of `typedef int  BOOLEAN;`? `int` generally has better performance than the other types, because it's the natural word size of the machine, and therefore often the most performant.

Comment: @BiteBytes: And why not use the built-in boolean type? Homebrew macros/aliases should not be used if there are standard types/macros!

Comment: @Olaf some people restrict there code to c89/90.

Comment: @BiteBytes: Those people should read the wiki-page of the C tag and eventually move to the 21st century.

Comment: @Olaf by 21th century you mean c11?

Comment: @BiteBytes: Optimally, yes. But for booleans and most common constructs C99, i.e. modern C would be sufficient. After all C11 mostly added features, but was not such a major change to C99 as C99 was to ancient C (and for VLAs it was a kotau to commerical compiler manufacturers who don't want to leave the 1980ies).

Comment: The function as written does not make any sense. The ideomatic way is to return the pointer to the string, that way the function cannot fail. If you want to _copy_ the string, you exactly have to do this, which you don't. If the `const char []` is just an example, you could return a malloc'ed pointer, a null pointer on failure. which would be the ideomatic way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement

```
pu8Version = &MAL_Version[0];
```

only modifies the local pointer `pu8Version` in `GetVersion()` and that doesn't change `buffer` in `main()`.

Instead of:

```
pu8Version = &MAL_Version[0];
```

you can *copy* the `MAL_Version` to `buffer` with:

```
strcpy(pu8Version, MAL_Version);
```

If you really don't need a copy of `MAL_Version`, you can also return the pointer to `MAL_Version` directly. Something like:

```
/* Function to return Version string */
const char *GetVersion(void)
{
    return MAL_Version;
}

int main(void) {
   const char *version = GetVersion();
   printf("\n%s", version);
}
```

---

Note that you don't define a "BOOLEAN" yourself. `bool` (from `<stdbool.h>` header) type is available in C since C99.

Answer (score 0):

The function parameter `pu8Version` is the local *copy* of the pointer passed.

You change `pu8Version` to point to the static string `MAL_Version` which prints correctly. On returning fom the function, the changed version of `pu8Version` is forgotten.

The original `unsigned char buffer[10];` is *uninitialised* and remains so, so rubbish is printed.

Note you cannot copy a C string with the `=` operator. What that does is to change the pointer, but not what it is pointing to. You should use `strcpy`.

Comment: There is only one place where you actually can - array initialisation char x[]="asdfghj";

Answer (score 0):

Or you can pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
/* Function to return Version string */
BOOLEAN GetVersion ( unsigned char **pu8Version )
{
    BOOLEAN success = FALSE;

    if(*pu8Version != NULL)
    {
        *pu8Version = MAL_Version;
        success = TRUE;
        printf("\r\nTRUE");
        printf("\r\n%s", *pu8Version);
    }

    return success;
}

int main() {
   unsigned char *buffer;

   GetVersion(&buffer);
   printf("\r\n%s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: `buffer` is only one character, I want to return 10. I am already doing this and facing problem.

Comment: @Swanand I forgot the `*` before `buffer`.

Comment: @Swanand And to avoid the warning complaining about discarding the `const` qualifier, try to declare `*buffer` and `**pu8Version` as constants too.